# ViewComponent with optional parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am creating a set of View Components that represent filters on different views. They work great so far, but I don't understand this behavior I am experiencing.

If I use declare two InvokeAsync:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string name)
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string name, string title)
```

Then I get this:

> Error: View component 'MyViewComponent' must have exactly one public method named 'InvokeAsync' or 'Invoke'.

But if I do something like this instead:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string name, string title = "")
```

Then this happens:

```
<vc:my name="Hello" title="Hello"></vc:my> // Gets rendered
<vc:my name="Hello" title=""></vc:my>  // Gets rendered
<vc:my name="Hello"></vc:my> // Doesn't call InvokeAsync
```

So, is it possible at all to use default parameters? I cannot use a Model for this (client requirements)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this Github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1266), it doesn't seem like it will be done by the team.

> @rynowak Apr 29, 2017 - I'm going to move it in and mark it up for grabs. At this point locking down our public APIs and completing the tooling story needs to take priority.

---

**Update 4 years later:** This was finally accepted for .NET 6 and this should now work!

Comment: Hi Camilo. I think it will not be fixed.The GIthub issue is linked twice and then the last Issue closed is https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/1266 where it's explained that it will not be closed.

Comment: Hi @gsharp, it seems to be up-for-grabs, so maybe it will be done at some point. Probably needs more community requests for the team to look at it.

Comment: FYI: As per the same [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5011#issuecomment-594340314), this is now earmarked for .NET 5.0. A welcome update!

Comment: The fix didn't make it for .NET 5.0 but sounds like it's fixed in the most recent .NET 6 preview (#6 from July).

Comment: For anyone else who is trying to use Invoke() with default parameters. This fix was only applied to InvokeAsync() and doesn't work when using Invoke() in .net 7.0

Answer (score 1):

From other comments it sounds like this might be fixed in .NET 6, but if you need a solution now, a simple one is to create an options container class and pass the parameters in that.

```
public class MyComponentOptions
{
    public string Name;
    public string Title;
}
```

Your Invoke method takes the options:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(MyComponentOptions options)
```

In your HTML you can pass them like this:

```
@{ var bob = new MyComponentOptions { Name = "Bob" }; }
<vc:my-component options="@bob" />

@{ var alice = new MyComponentOptions { Name = "Alice", Title = "Developer" }; }
<vc:my-component options="@alice" />
```

^-- Both of these work.