# ASP.NET Core : view component with 2 invokes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have many view components and used in a Page Maker software.
But now I need make a dynamic setting page for each view component.

Something like this:

```
@Component.InvokeAsync("Image");
@Component.InvokeSettingPage("Image");
```

or any idea to make something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you cannot have two invokes for a ViewComponent. Starting with .net core 6, you can have multiple properties in the InvokeAsync method and then, based on these properties, you can decide what you render or what would you like to do.

More info you can find here - [ViewComponent with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208838/viewcomponent-with-optional-parameters)

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The parameters will be passed to the InvokeAsync method. The PriorityList view component developed in the article is invoked from the Views/ToDo/Index.cshtml view file. In the following, the InvokeAsync method is called with two parameters

```
namespace ViewComponentSample.ViewComponents
{
    public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly ToDoContext db;

        public PriorityListViewComponent(ToDoContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
            return View(items);
        }
        private Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            return db.ToDo.Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone &&
                                 x.Priority <= maxPriority).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("PriorityList", new { maxPriority = 4, isDone = true })
```

Here is a sample code to render the component dynamically.You Can Pass Paramters whit Json in ViewComponent Like this

```
 @foreach(var component in Model.SelectedComponent)
    {
        <div class="component">
            @await Component.InvokeAsync(component.Name, component.OptionalJsonString)
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: this is not answer of my question